# Error while using mutt :gnutls_handshake: A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.!

Tags: gmail, mutt

I am getting this error "gnutls_handshake: A TLS packet with unexpected length was received." again and again while trying to use mutt. I am using Ubuntu 11.04 32-bit.I searched about the problem and couldn't found head and tail about it.

Is it a OS specific problem(unlikely because the same muttrc worked in fedora 16) or there is something wrong with my .muttrc

## .muttrc

```
{# A basic .muttrc for use with Gmail

# Change the following six lines to match your Gmail account details
set imap_user = "email@gmail.com"
set imap_pass = "password"
set smtp_url = "smtp://email@smtp.gmail.com:587/"
set smtp_pass = "password"
set from = "email@gmail.com"
set realname = "Vinit Kumar"

# Change the following line to a different editor you prefer.
set editor = "vim"



# Basic config, you can leave this as is
set folder = "imaps://imap.gmail.com:993"
set spoolfile = "+INBOX"
set imap_check_subscribed
set hostname = gmail.com
set mail_check = 120
set timeout = 300
set imap_keepalive = 300
set postponed = "+[GMail]/Drafts"
set record = "+[GMail]/Sent Mail"
set header_cache=~/.mutt/cache/headers
set message_cachedir=~/.mutt/cache/bodies
set certificate_file=~/.mutt/certificates
set move = no
set include
set sort = 'threads'
set sort_aux = 'reverse-last-date-received'
set auto_tag = yes
ignore "Authentication-Results:"
ignore "DomainKey-Signature:"
ignore "DKIM-Signature:"
hdr_order Date From To Cc
alternative_order text/plain text/html *
auto_view text/html
bind editor <Tab> complete-query
bind editor ^T complete
bind editor <space> noop 

# Gmail-style keyboard shortcuts
macro index,pager y "<enter-command>unset trash\n <delete-message>" "Gmail archive     message"
macro index,pager d "<enter-command>set trash=\"imaps://imap.googlemail.com/[GMail]     /Bin\"\n <delete-message>" "Gmail delete message"
macro index,pager gi "<change-folder>=INBOX<enter>" "Go to inbox"
macro index,pager ga "<change-folder>=[Gmail]/All Mail<enter>" "Go to all mail"
macro index,pager gs "<change-folder>=[Gmail]/Starred<enter>" "Go to starred messages"
macro index,pager gd "<change-folder>=[Gmail]/Drafts<enter>" "Go to drafts"}
```

Comment: Same situation here.  As far as I can tell it looks like a gnutls bug, but I got stuck there.

Comment: perhaps best to try questions like this [over at SU](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mutt)

Comment: Did anyone ever find a solution to this?